# Pylibftdi versus PyFtdi - what is the difference?

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial, ftdi, libftdi

What's the difference between [pylibftdi](https://pylibftdi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [PyFtdi](https://eblot.github.io/pyftdi/index.html)? I have used PySerial before. But have not been able to use it on my current device that has an ftdi cable. That's how I stumbled across pylibftdi and PyFtdi. If I need to choose a platform agnostic library e.g. development on Windows and automation test runs on Linux, what would be a better choice?